Sky color other than blue
Is it possible to have a planet where humans can survive for >30min outside, where the sky color is anything but blue?
In anime and sci-fi, there are planets with a purple / green /red / yellow / ... sky. Could such planets actually exist and be habitable (not immediately deadly) for normal humans? I had a look at this question, but I am not sure if there is a combination where humans can survive outside.
Restrictions:

normal human without space suit / oxygen mask / any other kind of breathing apparatus or accessories beyond regular clothes must be able to survive outside for at least 30min under optimal weather conditions
There may be exposure damage, but nothing that is permanent, crippling or deadly after only 30min (kind of like sunburn). Repeated exposure <30min with enough time to heal in between should be possible and without long-term health consequences. May become scarring/permanent/deadly after >1h
sky color at high noon: black during night, white thanks to clouds, or reddish-orange during sunset does not count. Neither counts a once-every-week red dust storm or aurora lights - it should be the normal color of the sky

Question
Is such a planet possible? If so, how does the sky get the different color, and how long would humans be able to survive outside under optimal conditions?

I would suggest looking into a case like the 1991 eruption of Mt. Pinatubo. The surroundings were habitable by humans, but due to the high concentration of sulfur dioxide in the lower layers of clouds, light was dispersed very distinctly than the usual blue skies. The result was a pervasive shade of red-orange that lasted ~3 years! Adding a dispersion of particulate matter where humans cannot breathe them is a good way to change the color of the sky.

Would a tinted contact lens meet your conditions? The sky technically isn't any color, it's just looks that way for reasons, if another reason (a tinted contact lens) changes your perception, you could argue that it has changed the color of the sky.

Here have some more information about Rayleigh scattering. The short answer, our sunlight is kinda whitish, and the sky has all colors scattered through it, but shorter wavelengths simply scatter more, and thus our sky is blueish-white, turning our view of the sun yellow at the same time. You might get your wanted result with a sun that emits far more red/yellow/orange than blue, or by pumping A LOT of a light gas like helium in the upper atmosphere without killing everybody. But I don't think we can [tag:hard-science] prove that anyway.

No
That hard-science tag is ruthless. There's no room for equivocation. Purple, yellow... such skies cannot exist in a human-habitable context.
First of all, you have a problem with how humans perceive color. Earth's sky is actually purple. We perceive it as blue due to limitations in our eyesight. So when you ask with that hard-science tag how to get a yellow sky (which might happen due to something absorbing violet), the very first thing you need to care about is that the human eye is getting in the way of doing that. It's getting in the way a lot. So, no exotic colors due to the human eye.
Next, examine the chart found in this question. That sky color chart is based on atmospheric pressure and star color. You'll see that sky colors range from blue to orange.
For one thing, there are no green stars. There are many reasons (one of which is our eyesight...), but without a green star, you couldn't get (e.g.) a yellow atmosphere with the gasses humans need to breathe.
But that color chart is the way it is also because gasses humans can breath that are, indeed, gasses at temperatures humans can withstand scatter light in the blue-to-orange wavelengths. The process is called Rayleigh scattering Depending on specifics you can get some golds and reds (see sunsets, which mimic high-density atmospheres), but generally you're stuck with blue-to-orange. However, other than sunsets and sunrises, we don't have an example of any clear human-breathable atmosphere in the densities required to get those colors consistently — and the atmospheric densities might not allow humans to breathe for the >30min time you're requiring. Human lungs don't react well to very-high/very-low pressures without assistance.
You could get exotic colors by adding "stuff" to the atmosphere. Crystals, organics, etc. But to do that enough to get a ubiquitous color would compromise human respiration. Too much dust (etc.) in the air isn't healthy. Again, the hard-science tag is getting in the way of what we want. Humans need to survive without wearing filters all the time. So, no stuff at necessary quantities to get exotic colors.
You could hand wave some of this. In orther words, you could get a lovely yellow sky by suspending hydrogen in particulate dust of yellow apatite or heliodor such that the aggregate molecules have a lower density than the atmosphere so they rationally float in the upper atmosphere — and then ignore the fact that as electromagnetic energy strikes that fine dust it will break it apart, releasing the hydrogen and causing the dust to settle to the ground. But per the hard-science tag, that can't happen.
So, no. You can't have the colors you want.
And please remember. The hard-science tag shouldn't be used unless the science supporting the answer is what you need to build your world. If all you were doing was using the tag to try and force a higher quality answer or to "guarantee" you got the answer you wanted, you used the wrong tag.

The sky is purple the way Americans are named James Smith. There's just a spike at that index.

"Earth's sky is actually purple": Color is a sensation. It exists in the mind, and only in the mind. Color is not a physical quantity. There is no such thing as a "real" color independent of the human observer. If the average human observer observes that the sky is sky blue, it is sky blue. (And a working colorimeter or photo camera will also indicate or reproduce sky blue, because colorimeters and photo cameras are calibrated to indicate or reproduce the color observed by the average human observer.)

@jbh Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! That gave me the information I needed in a way that I actually understood.

"Human lungs don't react well to very-high/very-low pressures..." High pressure isn't too much of an issue, actually, as long as there's not a big differential between the environment and the inside of your body. E.g. on SCUBA the gas you breathe is regulated to match ambient pressure, which means that on a very deep dive you're breathing gas which might be at 20+ bar. Chemistry can be a problem, though: O2 is toxic above ~1.6 atm partial pressure, so 21% O2 @ 20 bar would be quite bad (that'd be > 4 atm ppO2).  So planets with dense atmospheres would need lower %O2 to be survivable, etc..

@AlexP While color perception is a human phenomenon, color itself is not. It is a measurable physical property.

@Corey: Yes, in the sense that color can be specified absolutely in a color space such as CIE XYZ or sRGB or whatever. On the other hand, the very definition of those color spaces comes from experimental measurement of the sensation experienced by many humans, averaged out to approximate a standard human observer. (And, moreover, even when color is specified absolutely in a standardized color space and the human observer has perfectly normal color vision, the actual color experienced depends heavily on the specific scene and is does not necessarily match the measurement.)

@AlexP What you're really saying is that color names and their cultural significance is merely a human perception. 700nm light is 700nm light regardless of whether or not someone is in the woods to hear the proverbial tree fall. The reason I included all that I did about eyesight is because perception is part of the problem, but not enough to rationalize (e.g.) a green atmosphere in a [tag:hard-science] context.

@JBH: Color and wavelength are different things. Yes, if you know the wavelength of a monochromatic light source then you know what color a human will see; but the reverse is not true. If you know the color of a light source you cannot say anything much about what wavelengths might be present in it. As a practical example, at the top right of this page there is an orange button with the words Ask Question on it. Although the button is clearly orange, I would be willing to bet that the light does not contain any wavelength in the 590 to 625 nm range.

Blue or orange-ish. Probably.
We adapt to different illuminants. We see objects that reflect all light in random directions as being 'white' provided there is a reasonable amount of stimulus for our eye's cone. We are better at ignoring variations along the thermal locus from red to blue rather than perpendicular to it (green to pink).
Let us assume our atmosphere does not absorb a significant amount of light. Earth's sky looks blue because of Rayleigh scattering. The light is scattered by air molecules, which are much smaller than the wavelength of light, so they have more effect on the shorter wavelengths. The blue colour of the sky is made from the shorter wavelength which have been scattered, and the setting sun appears orange because the shorter wavelengths have been scattered in other directions. Any white object will reflect light from the sun and from the sky, so it will still appear white-ish.
Suppose the scattering is caused by particles that are larger than the wavelength of light. This is what happens after volcanic eruptions. The particles in the atmosphere can then scatter more long wavelengths, so the sky will appear orange, and the sun will look blue-white.
In both cases, the scattering from random particles varies only slowly with wavelength. If we could fill the atmosphere with exactly 0.55 nm particles - which is a bad idea and would probably give us all lung cancer - then this would scatter all wavelengths, and not just the green at 550 nm. You would need some structure such as a diffraction grating to give colours by scattering. Without this, the scattering peak will be so broad that it will hardly look coloured.
If you want a green sky, then the atmosphere is going to have to absorb light. There are not many coloured gases. The halogens would be deadly to us. I do not know for sure that there is no coloured gas that we can breathe, but it cannot be anything common, and it would have to be very common to have a whole atmosphere of it.
